# How to make rounded Pentagon with clip path css?

Tags: clip-path

I want to make rounded pentagon like this.
[rounded pentagon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5G1e.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use This Website, It'll help you
[Css clip](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)